# How can I delete all Wiki pages created by spammers except mine in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, sql

I Implemented a MediaWiki site but unfortunately somebody created thousands of pages through thousand of users.

Which query could I run for deleting all pages created by these users except mine?

MediaWiki pages are in `wiki_page` and `wiki_text` inside MediaWiki database but there is no field about who created those pages.

Largest table:

- `wiki_text`: 682MB
- `wiki_externallinks`:  162.5 MB
- `wiki_recentchange`:  95 MB
- `wiki_page`:  43 MB

  [Here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9194/mass-deletion-of-spam-revisions-in-mediawiki/45486), I find a possible answer to my problem but I'm blocked at the first step:

"Export articles created by you (presumably logged in as the WikiSysop user or similar)"

How can I export article made by me if in the table there is no field about user who created pages?

Comment: In the link you posted there is a description on how to manually delete all pages not created by you. (http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/45486/27664)

Comment: ok, so i have to run: "DELETE FROM revision WHERE rev_user != YOUR_USER_ID;" for revision page, then work on "page_latest" table and last use purgeOldText.php script for delete from wiki_text table.

Answer (score 2):

If you know some Python (or are not afraid to learn) you should approach this with [pywikibot](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot).

You can loop through `wiki.allpages()` and you can add some logic to decide whether to delete a page or not. Good criteria:

- Does the page contain specific words? E.g. related to drugs or porn.
- Does the page have wikilinks to other pages?
- Does the page have links from other pages?

(I can add a couple of Python lines here if there's any interest. Just let me know.)

Comment: Often, the sites created by spammers are **orphans*: Sites that have no other wiki sites link to them. That could be one of the criteria for deletion. I did this by hand for my club's media wiki which fortunately didn't have too many of them.